# Altair: How to use an aggregate that adds a facet (e.g., an extra column with the aggregate)?

Tags: python, altair

Aggregate and joinaggregate don't seem to be *quite* what I want here. I would like to add another facet to my plot that is an aggregation. I want to start with something like:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Dataset": ["A", "B", "A", "B"],
    "Variant": ["X", "X", "Y", "Y"],
    "Val": [1, 4, 7, 3],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

alt.Chart(df, mark="bar").encode(x="Variant:N", y="Val:Q", column="Dataset:N")
```

[image: Base data, no aggregation]

and then aggregate across all columns to generate a mean value, which will hopefully look something like:

[image: Base data + aggregation]

I can do this in Pandas. I'd like to do it in Altair if possible.

Bonus points: Aggregate with the geometric mean (not the arithmetic mean)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my answer is optimal, I don't think there is a way to add a new row within Altair. (Maybe I just don't know.) I decided to draw 3 graphs using conditional extraction. The first two graphs are drawn by conditional extraction and the average uses a transformation calculation. Finally, each graph is joined horizontally. I modified the y-axis scale and title to match the usual facet bluff. The answer to this question is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72731668/how-to-add-into-pandas-pivot-table-using-altair).

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Dataset": ["A", "B", "A", "B"],
    "Variant": ["X", "X", "Y", "Y"],
    "Val": [1, 4, 7, 3],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

conditions = df.Dataset.unique().tolist()+['Mean']
charts = []

for c in conditions:
    if c !='Mean':
        l = True if c == 'A' else False
        t = 'Val' if c == 'A' else ''
        chart = alt.Chart(df.loc[df['Dataset']==c], title=c).mark_bar().encode(
            x=alt.X('Variant:N'),
            y=alt.Y('Val:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0,7]), axis=alt.Axis(labels=l), title=t),
            )
    else:
        chart = alt.Chart(df, title=c).transform_aggregate(
            means = 'mean(Val)',
            groupby = ['Variant']
        ).mark_bar().encode(
            x = alt.X('Variant:N'),
            y = alt.Y('mean(means):Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0,7]), axis=alt.Axis(labels=False), title='')
        )
        
    charts.append(chart)

alt.hconcat(*charts).configure_scale(
        bandPaddingInner=0.03
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make a separate chart with your aggregation and then concatenate it to your 'data' chart. Then add some extra code to clean up the axis, titles ... to make it look a bit nicer.

```
base = alt.Chart(df, mark="bar").encode(x="Variant:N",)
chart1 = base.encode(y='Val:Q', column=alt.Column("Dataset:N").title(None))
chart2 = base.encode(y=alt.Y("mean(Val):Q").axis(domain=False, title=None, labels=False, ticks=False)).properties(title='Mean')

(chart1 | chart2).resolve_scale(y='shared')
```

[image: plot from code]